# search a word not containing something in "vi"

Tags: regex, search, vim, vi

I want to search words as following in "vi":

```
"AA" not followed by "BB" or "CC"
```

i.e.

```
AAXC... -- OK
AABB... -- NOT OK
AACC... -- NOT OK
```

Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vim supports regex searching and substituting http://vimregex.com/:

That is the desired regex:

```
AA((?!B{2})|(?!C{2}))
```

The above regex can be validate [here](http://regex101.com/).

---

In vim:

```
/^\(AA\)\(BB\)\@!.*$
```

will find all the `AA..` format strings and will skip `AABB` strings.

1. in order to skip `AACC` and `AABB` you can use:

   ```
   /^\(AA\)\(\(BB\)\|\(CC\)\)\@!.*$
   ```

   or equivalently:

   ```
   /^\(AA\)\(\(B\{2\}\)\|\(C\{2\}\)\)\@!.*$
   ```
2. eliminate the `^` from the strings if you want to find strings like
   `AAXC` inside string of the form `BAAXC`.

Comment: tried `\AA((?!B{2})|(?!C{2}))`, but ended up with `E486: Pattern not found: AA((?!B{2})|(?!C{2}))`

Comment: That is the regex see the vim string you need to look for

Answer (score 0):

You can search using regular expressions, just use A[^BC], if it's actually that simple (just characters, not words).

Comment: Unfortunately I need to search for words. Please see the modified post